# What is the difference between "might be" and "must be"?

Tags: word-choice

(C ) 7 —You look worried. What's wrong?

—I can't find my wallet anywhere. It________lost.

A. must be
B. might be

**Question:**
Which one is right? A or B?

Comment: Can you provide any further context?

Comment: See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Note that if that's a question on a quiz, the quiz is broken.

Comment: @HotLicks Analogous to "How long is a piece of string?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just a test or homework exercise, from an unknown and incompetent text.

Comment: MIGHT: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/might  MUST: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/must

Comment: " Which one is right? A or B?". Both are correct responses as a reaction.

Answer (score 3):

Might be implies that there is a possibility it is lost. Must be lost states there is no other possibility.

Comment: Of course, "must" is sometimes used as an exaggeration.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find your wallet anywhere, it **is** lost:

> **lost** *adjective* **1.1** Unable to be found.
>  <sub>Source: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/lost)</sub>

But if you must use a modal auxiliary verb, you'll have to choose **A. *must be***; it's the modal we use  for certainty—for deductions and conclusions:

> *I can't find my wallet anywhere. It must be lost.*

That means that since you are unable to find your wallet, you have concluded that it is lost.

Or, as we say around here . . . [*No shit, Sherlock*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_shit,_Sherlock).

Comment: But 'lost' is also used pragmatically to mean 'irretrievably lost' rather than 'temporarily misplaced'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I think you mean that the other way around -- that it can be temporarily misplaced rather than irretrievably lost. That is, it *might* be lost. But given the test choice between *must* and *might* -- where only one is correct -- logic dictates *must*.

Comment: Yes; I should have written 'the pragmatic usage comes somewhere along the "I don't know _when_ I'll find it" to "I'll never see it again" continuum. 'Lost' is also used in the 'definitely gone forever' sense, eg when one drops one's wallet into the mouth of an active volcano. _But this isn't a question for ELU._

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely b), because "might be" implies that you are not sure if it's stolen, while "must be" means you are 100% sure that it's stolen, which you are not.

Comment: But 'stolen' is not part of the question.

Comment: @Pig Gaming: I would  disagree. In this case, since the wallet has not been found anywhere, it must be lost. In this case, must is a presumption, not an imperative.